# How to do mysql_fetch_assoc in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I do the following in mysqli prepare statement?

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $data:
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the MySQLi version of the functions:

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
return $data;
```

That should do it, you also might want to take a look at:

- http://php.net/mysqli
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: just tried it, and it works. 

@the downvoter: if your criticism is that this solution is not "clean" (the object oriented version in the other answer is "preferred" after all), then say so in a comment. Otherwise people could get the impression that the answer here is actually wrong, which it isn't.

Comment: Thank you, @mathheadinclouds. I only corrected OP's code, so he wouldn't have to go from learning about mysqli to learning about OOP.

Answer (score 6):

That's pretty simple after you've created the connection to mysql somewhere:

```
<?php
// create the connection to mysql.
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
?>
```

The refer to the mysqli object when you need to do a query or do something else.

```
<?php
// get the result object.
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
// fetch the result row.
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

return $data;
?>
```

Then at some point (if you have a class, you can write a destructor) you should close the connection to mysql if you won't need it anymore.

```
<?php
$mysqli->kill($mysqli->thread_id);
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

You can do much more with the result object you have. 
So read more about the `MySQLi_Result` here:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php