# php mysql database select

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm to retrieve some variables from database say a mobile number that is to be the recipient of a sms. When I try passing it as a service argument I get stdClass Object ( ) ...How do I pass it? Kindly, any one?

sample code:

```
$sql = "SELECT msisdn FROM customer WHERE id = 5";


$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);



        $mobilenumber = $resultarr;
        $message = $_POST['Message'];

        $serviceArguments = array(
                "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
                "message" => $message
        );

        $client = new SoapClient("http://52.38.60.160:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL");

        $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);

        return $result;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_assoc in mysqli?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689564/mysql-fetch-assoc-in-mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)** .Fetch a result row as an associative array

To get mobile number form  `$resultarr` you need to to

```
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);// fetch data
$mobilenumber=$resultarr['msisdn'];// get mobile number from array
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked very well.